# COALESCE on a single table

Tags: t-sql, coalesce

I have the below table and i would like to get the below result with using the COALESCE . Any help will be appreciated.

[image: Coleasce]

Thanks
sam

Comment: Why no `Brand2` in the 3rd group?

Comment: Why do you want to use COALESCE for this? Do you know what that function actually does?

Answer (score 2):

This is the generally accepted standard for how to concatenate values contained over multiple rows.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    LEFT(brands, LEN(brands) -2) brands
FROM 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT ID, 
            (
                SELECT
                    brand + ', ' [text()]
                FROM 
                    myTable brands 
                WHERE 
                    brands.id = ids.id
                FOR XML PATH ('')
            ) brands
        FROM
            myTable ids
        GROUP BY 
            ID
    ) m
```

Of course adding coalesce (null, value) for any given value will meet your criteria for using the coalesce function but this is doesn't add functionality or leverage the coalesce function in a useful way.